# In NestJs, I added Redis as cache manager, when I specify {ttl : 0} it throws a type error, it was working before

Tags: redis, nestjs

I am using Redis as the cache manager in NestJs project. I was using a code like:

```
await this.productCacheManager.set('products/time', data, { ttl: 60} )
```

When I delete the ttl argument or just put 60 there, it doesn't work and it immediately  removes the record from redis, so I was using { ttl: 60} which was working until now.
I do not know what happend but now it throws an error like:

> Argument of type '{ ttl: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

The parameter I am typing is a number...

Trying to make it work again like before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `cache-manager` v4 and `cache-manager-redis-store` v2, you need to pass an options object, as in

```js
cache.set(key, value, { ttl: 60 }) // in seconds
```

(And that's because the redis store v2 code *expects* an object)

If you are using `cache-manager` v5, though, you may pass an integer, although I've not yet been able to make `cache-manager-redis-store@^3` work well with `cache-manager@^5`.

```js
cache.set(key, value, 60000) // in milliseconds with v5!
```

⚠️ As of today (2023-02-24), NestJS recommends using cache-manager **v4**.

> Source: [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#:%7E:text=cache%2Dmanager%20version%204%20uses%20seconds%20for%20TTL%20(Time%2DTo%2DLive).%20The%20current%20version%20of%20cache%2Dmanager%20(v5)%20has%20switched%20to%20using%20milliseconds%20instead.%20NestJS%20doesn%27t%20convert%20the%20value%2C%20and%20simply%20forwards%20the%20ttl%20you%20provide%20to%20the%20library.%20In%20other%20words%3A) as for the seconds/milliseconds consideration.
>
> The object vs number specification, I found out myself by trying different combinations and parsing the redis store code.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this answer is too late. But if anyone experiences the same problem, you can try this method.
i use these dependencies:

> "cache-manager": "^5.2.3", "cache-manager-redis-store": "^3.0.1",

```
await this.cacheManager.set(
  key,
  value,
  {ttl: 1000} as any
);
```

Comment: nice...  but ttl is mills



```set: (key: string, value: unknown, ttl?: Milliseconds) => Promise<void>;```


I think there has a bug with  `caching.d.ts`

Answer (score 2):

With cache-manager v5, you can use { ttl: time_in_seconds }, for example:

```js
await this.cacheManager.set(key, value, { ttl: 60 }); // ttl 60 seconds
```

If you are working with typescript you can use CacheStore interface from cache-manager.

```js
import { CacheStore } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use your recommended `CacheStore` for my CacheManager and it works

Comment: works for "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^1.0.0", "cache-manager": "^5.2.1", "cache-manager-redis-store": "^3.0.1",

Answer (score -1):

You only need to pass the number, not the object `{ ttl: 60}`, just use `60`, because here it is only reserved for til and it knows it's going to be a number.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gets deleted immediately no matter what number I give, even 0, that's why I switched to {ttl: 60}, and it worked this way, now it doesn't again...

Comment: See the answer I provided. I've made it work with a specific combination of versions.

Comment: Thank you oliver, will reflect this also on our stack